# Issues regarding jetty migration from 9 to 10\11

Tags: jetty, jetty-9

I am trying migrate our application from Jetty 9 to Jetty 10 and Jetty 11.

However following classes\interfaces from Jetty 9 are not available in Jetty 10\11.
MemSession
AbstractSessionManager
AbstractSessionIdManager

Which are replacement classes for above?

I have checked Jetty documentation, however it is not much helpful. And there is no migration guide available.

Comment: Show your code, what are you trying to do?  There are often other (better) choices than what you are doing. - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You have stated you are going from Jetty 9.3.x to 11.x, that would be major version updates of 9.3 -> 9.4 -> 10.0 -> 11.0 (so 3 major version updates, as Jetty versioning is `<servlet_support>.<major_version>.<minor_version>`).  You cannot expect classes to stick around between multiple major version updates.

The 3 classes you have referenced, do not exist in the most recent versions of Jetty 9.

See: https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/tree/jetty-9.4.51.v20230217/jetty-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/session

`MemSession` - not sure what you are referring to here.  There is no concept of unique `Session` implementations in Jetty 10.  There is only 1 internal implementation that you have no ability to replace or override behavior of.

`AbstractSessionManager` - this class does not exist either.
However, the whole `SessionManager` (the interface) concept was removed in Jetty 9.4.0, it is not present in Jetty 10 onwards.  There is no replacement for this concept. (it was barely used in Jetty 9.3.x anyway, and newer Servlet specs rendered this concept useless in Jetty)

`AbstractSessionIdManager` - this class also does not exist in Jetty 9.
However, there is a `org.eclipse.jetty.server.SessionIdManager` interface in Jetty 9, and it operates basically the same way as in Jetty 10+

There is only 1 implementation with Jetty, `org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.DefaultSessionIdManager`

There are many features of Jetty Session handling.

Comment: These classes were available as part of jetty-server-9.3.12.v20160915 release 
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-distribution/9.3.12.v20160915/

Comment: https://archive.eclipse.org/jetty/9.3.13.v20161014/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/session/MemSession.html
https://archive.eclipse.org/jetty/9.0.0.M0/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/session/AbstractSessionIdManager.html
https://archive.eclipse.org/jetty/9.0.0.M0/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/session/AbstractSessionManager.html

Comment: Jetty 9.3.x was declared End of Life back in early 2020.   Keep in mind that Jetty versioning is `<servlet_support>.<major_version>.<minor_ver>`.

Comment: So can you please suggest which classes\interfaces should be used which were removed from 9.3.x? i.e. AbstractSessionIdManager , AbstractSessionManager and MemSession     Thanks

Comment: You are referencing `M0` versions (unstable milestones), nothing in those versions should have been used long term.

Comment: I updated the answer, but the lack of details in your question is making this difficult - See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask